# Does IdSchedulerOfThreadPool limit the simultaneous-connection count?

Tags: delphi, indy, realthinclient

If I assign an TIdSchedulerOfThreadPool to my IdTCPServer, will I still be limited to the number of simultaneous connections?

My IdTCPServer properties are :

```
 ListenQueue : 30
   MaxConnections : 0
   ReuseSocket rsTrue
   Scheduler :MyIdSchedulerOfThreadPool
   TerminateWaitTime : 5000
```

MyIdSchedulerOfThreadPool's properties :

```
Scheduler: MyIdSchedulerOfThreadPool
MaxThreads = 0
PoolSize = 0
ThreqdPriority = tpNormal
```

No coding; I just assign the MyIdSchedulerOfThreadPool to Scheduler.

---

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've asked two entirely unrelated questions. Please pick *one* to ask here in this post. Then [edit] the post to remove the other question, and post it separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TIdTCPServer.MaxConnections` property controls how many simultaneous clients are allowed to be connected at a time.

The `TIdSchedulerOfThread.MaxThreads` property controls how many simultaneous threads are allowed to be running at a time (idle or otherwise).

The `TIdSchedulerOfThreadPool.PoolSize` property controls how many simultaneous idle threads are allowed to be in the pool at a time.

So when you have a `TIdSchedulerOfThread...` assigned, the max number of simultaneous connections is really the smaller value between the `MaxConnections` and `MaxThreads` properties, since each client connection requires a thread to manage it.

Comment: many thanks as my above IdTcpServer settings is it simultaneous-connection limit ?

Comment: You have all of properties set to 0, so all of the limits are effectively unlimited.

Comment: Remy, so the server will not be limited to simultaneous-connections

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for.